# Tell ido-find-file not to run py-shell on python-mode

Tags: python, ido-find-file

I have python-mode installed.

When editing any python script, if I have the point over any python statement, I noted that when using ido-mode and using any ido-find function, py-shell runs, opening a new buffer for the python shell, and then ido prompting me for the file to find.

When point is not on any python statement, this behavior doesn't occur.

Is there some kind of conflict between python-mode and ido-mode ? I have been looking if anything gets defined making this strange (and annoying) behavior but couldn't find anything.

How can I tell ido-find commands to stop running py-shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by upgrading python-mode, guess was a bug on the version I was using